# CSS: a:hover leaking into other elements?

Tags: css, hover

I've added the below CSS to my child style.css

```
.um-faicon-linkedin-square.social-media-link:hover {
    color: blue!important;
}
```

But it seems that the a:hover that's in the original style.css is leaking through?
It sometimes turns green and sometimes turns blue?

```
a:hover {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? It would be helpful to see what these styles are applying to.

Comment: Yes, additional code is necessary. Otherwise we cannot inspect, what can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys!
You can see an example on this page:
http://www.evolvedmedia.com.au/who-is-your-mr-psoas/

On the left-hand side I'm trying to style the social buttons on author profile.